# Phoenix so slow? Please help to improve its performance

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I learned elixir just because a lot of articles in the internet are promising that's its response time is less than a millisecond. I built my first app yesterday and I can't find it's performance faster than rails. What's happening?

Let me explain my app. It implements basic authentication mechanism provided by `ecto-secure-password` package:

```
defmodule HelloPhoenix.User do
  use HelloPhoenix.Web, :model
  use SecurePassword

  schema "users" do
    field :first_name, :string
    field :last_name, :string
    field :username, :string

    has_secure_password
  end
end
```

Here's my controller:

```
defmodule HelloPhoenix.SessionController do
  use HelloPhoenix.Web, :controller

  def create(conn, %{ "session" => %{ "username" => username, "password" => password }}) do
    if user = HelloPhoenix.User.authenticate(HelloPhoenix.Repo.get_by(HelloPhoenix.User, username: username), password) do
      conn
      |> put_session(:user_id, user.id)
      |> json(UserSerializer.run(user))
    else
      conn
      |> put_status(422)
      |> json(%{})
    end
  end
end
```

So, I'm using these commands:

```
MIX_ENV=prod mix compile
MIX_ENV=prod mix phoenix.server
```

Response time on both failed & successful authentications is about ~130ms, while rails response time here is ~150ms. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'm guessing I know the answer since this is a HelloWorld style app, but how many users are in the table? Using `Repo.get_by` could cause a full table scan if you're not indexing properly, though I doubt with only a single user that's the slow part.

Comment: Also, when in the `dev` environment, the SQL queries should be printed, with the execution time at the end of the line. Could you please add those so we can see if it's the database or the elixir code slowing things down? (Simply omit the `MIX_ENV=prod` from the `mix phoenix.server` command)

Comment: @CodyPoll `OK query=0.5 ms` only one query

Answer (score 6):

It's "slow" because password hashing functions (bcrypt in this case) are intentionally slow, so as to avoid brute force attacks. I don't think you should worry about it, as you only need to hash when the users logins, not on every request. An attacker, on the other hand, would need to pay the price every time he tries a password.

However, it is advisable to reduce the rounds when running test code, as creating a user on every request will slow down your tests to a crawl. Slow tests make developers not run them as often, which is not good.

`ecto-secure-password` uses `comeonin`, therefore, if you want to make it faster on test environments (**do not** use this on production, as it is not secure at all), you can configure it to use only a few rounds.

Append this to your config/test.exs:

```
config :comeonin, :bcrypt_log_rounds, 4
config :comeonin, :pbkdf2_rounds, 1
```

And voilá, production is secured while your tests are still fast (my tests went from taking 15 seconds to < 1s).

Answer (score 1):

Since v5 of the `comeonin` library, the hashing implementation has been split to respective libraries, so the configuration provided will need to change depending on the hashing library used:

```
config :bcrypt_elixir, :log_rounds, 1

config :pbkdf2_elixir, :rounds, 1

config :argon2_elixir,
  t_cost: 1,
  m_cost: 8
```

Comment: Recommended in the docs for pbkdf2_elixir here
https://github.com/riverrun/pbkdf2_elixir#installation